# My text view disappear when i try to remove the auto focus

Tags: android, textview

What i have is two Auto Complete Text View and what i am trying to do is i want when i start to write in anyone one of them .. i want the other one to be disabled or hidden .. and this is what i have tried , here is my xml code :

```
  <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relative1"
                android:background="@drawable/down"
                 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                 android:focusable="true" >

                   <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
                           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          />

                       <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/txtsearch2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And here is my java code :

```
if(textView.isFocusable()==true){// text view is the first one
                        textView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);// and here is the other one
                        active=1;
                    }else if(textView2.isFocusable()==true){
                        textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        active=2;
                    }
```

But when i run it what i get is that text view 2 disappear from the beginning .. and what i want is only when i made a focus on anyone of them , the other one disappear .. can anyone help me?

Comment: from my understanding what isFocusable means is, that this not returning true if the view is focused. It returns true if the view can get the focus. So instead of isFocusable(), You have to use isFocused()

Comment: isFocusable() determines if the view CAN be focused not IS focused

Comment: @erik... :) same comment to the same time :)

Comment: it worked please add it as answer so i can vote it .. but still when i make one of them focus i want the other one to disappear .. it wont !! why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable the focus of your first AutoCompleteTextViewbecause when ou start your activity it will automaticaly start with selected the first AutoCompleteTextView.

No sure how to do this but try :

```
EditText.setSelected(false);
```

or try in your xml to change the focus.

Say if it helps

Comment: i fixed the focus problem but still the visibility is not working

Comment: try isSelected() instead of isFocusable()

Comment: like this : `if (textView2.isSelected()) {
       textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                  
    } else {                
       textView.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }`

Comment: what's happening exactly ? do you see if you go in this part of code and when ?

Comment: yes i have changed it to this .. but still i see the both text view when one of them is selected

Comment: what i mean is : if you put a logcat in this part do you enter in it or not ?